# Make a folder that is named that day's date in this format 123113

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a bat file to back up my data HD (d:) to my exterior USB HD called H:\

For example

```
cd\ 
XCOPY D:\*.* H:\Mark\ /S/E/Y 
Pause
```

I want to make a folder in H and then dump the back up into that folder called (todays date)  in this format 123113.

Comment: `mkdir %date%` gets you close - I think the format will be your system's default though.

Comment: Under unix/linux it's `mkdir -p \`date +"%Y/%m/%d/"\``

Answer (score 2):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

The variable `datestamp` can be used to xcopy into that folder - xcopy will create the folder.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%MM%%DD%%YYYY%"

XCOPY "D:\*.*" "H:\Mark\%datestamp%\" /S/E/Y 

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%date%` Environment Variable here. However, you may not be able to use it directly due to illegal file name characters that could be present (`/` for example).

You can be quite specific about how the folder name is constructed:

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%A in ('date/t') do (
set DateDay=%%A
set DateMonth=%%B
set DateYear=%%C
)

set CurrentDate=%DateMonth%-%DateDay%-%DateYear%

md %CurrentDate%
```

But it does depend on your system's date format, in that you may need to swap 'DateDay' with 'DateMonth' to get US or UK flavoured equivalents. Example pinched wholesale from [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/create-a-folder-with-current-date/).

Comment: Note that there may not be illegal characters - my format is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Another problem is that it's possible to zero-suppress date elements, so you should `set DateDay=0%%A` within the `FOR` and `set ...%DateDay:~-2%... ` to pick up the last 2 characters of the resultant `DateDay`